# Access MenuItemCollection based on caption text

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

I am using a [`ContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) and have added some `Menu`'s to the [`MenuItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.menuitems.aspx) [`MenuItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.menuitemcollection.aspx) by doing the following:

```
private const string ADD_MENU_ITEM = "Add";
private const string REMOVE_MENU_ITEM = "Remove";
...
mContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(ADD_MENU_ITEM, new EventHandler(...));
mContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(REMOVE_MENU_ITEM, new EventHandler(...));
...
```

Now later, I would like to access the `Menu` from the `MenuItemCollection` based on the caption text.  So something like this:

```
Menu m = mContextMenu.MenuItems[ADD_MENU_ITEM]; // This doesnt work
```

I know that I could use the index, but I feel like there should be a way to get the `Menu` based on the caption name, since that is how its added.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
We can't go by caption, we have to enumerate through items and compare the text.

```
            var enumerator = node.ContextMenu?.MenuItems?.GetEnumerator();
            while ((bool)enumerator?.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = (MenuItem)enumerator.Current;
                if (item.Text == command)
                {
                    var menuItemCollection = item.MenuItems;
                    menuItemCollection.Remove(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using the existing API - you have to get creative. I know it makes sense because that's how you call the constructor, but that's just their way of saving you time when making new MenuItems, not how it's organized internally.

I might maintain a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary whose keys are the caption strings, and values are references to the MenuItem objects, then create a wrapper function that adds the menu item to the menu and the Dictionary. Removing those Dictionary entries when the menu items change is a different exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (I'm assuming C#3 or higher)

```
mContextMenu.MenuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Text == text);
```

On a related note, I don't know what your intentions are but you might want to take a look at the `Tag` property in `MenuItem`. Is is specifically made to store private data so that you don't have to rely on the caption or dictionaries to store information.